# Slicing and arranging dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to arrange the data from a data frame into multiple dataframes or groups. The input data is

```
id  channel path
15  direct  a1
15  direct  a2
15  direct  a3
15  direct  a4
213 paid    b2
213 paid    b1
2222    direct  as25
2222    direct  dw46
2222    direct  32q
3111    paid    d32a
3111    paid    23ff
3111    paid    www32
3111    paid    2d2
```

The desired output should be like

```
id  channel p1  p2      
213 paid    b2  b2      

id  channel p1  p2  p3  
2222    direct  as25    dw46    dw46    

id  channel p1  p2  p3  p4
15  direct  a1  a2  a3  a4
3111    paid    d32a    23ff    www32   2d2
```

Please tell the way i can achieve it. Thanks

Comment: Use code blocks instead of images, that would make it easy for others to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create helper column `cols` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).
Then you need find length of [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) columns (substract first 2) and
[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by this `length`. Last [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) columns in each group:

```
df['cols'] = 'p' + (df.groupby('id')['id'].cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'channel'], 
                    columns='cols', 
                    values='path', 
                    aggfunc='first').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print df1
     id channel    p1    p2     p3    p4
0    15  direct    a1    a2     a3    a4
1   213    paid    b2    b1   None  None
2  2222  direct  as25  dw46    32q  None
3  3111    paid  d32a  23ff  www32   2d2

print df1.apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum() - 2 , axis=1)
0    4
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64

for i, g in df1.groupby(df1.apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum() - 2 , axis=1)):
    print i
    print g.dropna(axis=1)
2
    id channel  p1  p2
1  213    paid  b2  b1
3
     id channel    p1    p2   p3
2  2222  direct  as25  dw46  32q
4
     id channel    p1    p2     p3   p4
0    15  direct    a1    a2     a3   a4
3  3111    paid  d32a  23ff  www32  2d2
```

For storing  you can use `dictionary` of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs={i: g.dropna(axis=1)         
    for i, g in df1.groupby(df1.apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum() - 2 , axis=1))}

#select DataFrame with len=2    
print dfs[2]
    id channel  p1  p2
1  213    paid  b2  b1

#select DataFrame with len=3       
print dfs[3]
     id channel    p1    p2   p3
2  2222  direct  as25  dw46  32q
```

Comment: I am getting an error
 # renamer function if passed a dict [TypeError: must pass an index to rename]

Comment: I think you have to use `pandas` version `0.18.0`. But if your version is lower, omit `.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: I am applying it on large amount of data and after converting to pivot, the order of row headers is not sequential. Its like
p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15 p16 p17 p18 p19 p20 p21 p22 p23 p24 p25 p26 p27 p28 p29 p30 p31 p1019 p102 p1020 p1021 p1022 p1023 p1024 p1025 p1026 p1027 p1028 p1029 p103 p1030 p1031 p1032 p1033 p1034 p1035 p1036 p1037 p1038 p1039 p104 p1040 p1041 p1042 p1043 p1044 p1045 p1046 p1047 p1048 p1049 p105 p1050 p1051 p1052 p1053 p1054 p1055 p1056 p1057 p1058 p1059 p106 p1060 p1061 p1062 p1063 p1064 p1065 
and more in a smimilar way

Comment: I think you can add to function `groupby` parameter `sort=False`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109540/discussion-between-jezrael-and-nishant-ranjan).